# very simple Z Normal axis rotation

Tags: normals, constraints, axis

new to Blender, so please forgive if obvious.I have been looking for an answer on this....

Goal: Simple object (e.g. cube) , once rotated 45 degrees, can have rotation on its Z Normal animated.

I have tried using constraints, but not getting anywhere. I have tried parenting to an Empty. No luck.The object still wants to rotate on the Z of Global. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Let's see if I understand: you have a cube that is not aligned to the XYZ axes:

[image]

If you want to rotate it along its **Local Z axis**, then you only have to do <kbd>R</kbd>, then <kbd>Z</kbd> **twice** ("Rot: along local Z" appears in the status bar):

[image]

However if you want to **animate** the rotation of the object through keyframes, you first need to set its *Rotation mode* to "***Quaternion***":

[image]

That's the result with the default *Rotation Mode* ("Euler") and "Quaternion":

[image]